# Submenu hidden behind content

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I've got problem with side menu, I tried to use z-index, but it doest work ;( menu is under web content..

Please help:
here is [page](http://ptp.krakow.pl/czlonkostwo/)

Comment: In future, please post relevant code to your question here on Stack Overflow - presumably you will be making changes to your linked page, at which point, this page becomes useless to future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely *where* you were applying the z-index. I added a positive z-index to the sidebar's container and I'm seeing no issues in Chrome. Add a positive z-index (I needed 99+) to the following:

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_0 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 981px) {
  .et_pb_row .et_pb_column.et-last-child,
  .et_pb_row .et_pb_column:last-child {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    z-index: 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping z-index on the main text here.

```
.et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column_3_4, .et_pb_gutters3.et_pb_row .et_pb_column_3_4 {
    width: 73.625%;
    z-index: 0;
```

}